# Como devolver un out parameter desde un procedimiento en Oracle de un NESTED_TABLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, stored-procedure, oracle-sqldeveloper

para un procedimiento de Oracle cree un tipo de dato que es el siguiente:

```
create or replace TYPE FILA_USUARIOr as object 
(
    ID                  NUMBER(4),
    ROLES_ID            NUMBER(1),
    PRIMER_NOMBRE       VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    SEGUNDO_NOMBRE      VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    PRIMER_APELLIDO     VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    SEGUNDO_APELLIDO    VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    CC                  NUMBER(10,0),
    EMAIL               VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)
);
```

y:

```
create or replace type NESTED_FILA_USUARIO as table of FILA_USUARIO;
```

cuando uso este tipo de dato en un bloque aninimo me funciona y puedo imprimir datos:

```
set serveroutput on; 
DECLARE  
    FILAUSU NESTED_FILA_USUARIO;
BEGIN
    select cast( multiset(select id, ROLES_ID, PRIMER_NOMBRE, SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, 
    PRIMER_APELLIDO, SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, CC, EMAIL from USUARIOS where id =  1) as 
    NESTED_FILA_USUARIO)
       into FILAUSU
    from usuarios;  

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FILAUSU(1).id||','||FILAUSU(1).ROLES_ID||','|| 
    FILAUSU(1).PRIMER_NOMBRE);
    END;
```

resultado del bloque:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de usar la misma consulta en un procedimiento me sale error. procedimiento:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE outnested(FILAUSU OUT NESTED_FILA_USUARIO)
AS
BEGIN
  select cast( multiset(select id, ROLES_ID, PRIMER_NOMBRE, SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, 
  PRIMER_APELLIDO, SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, CC, EMAIL from USUARIOS where id =  1) as 
  NESTED_FILA_USUARIO)
    into FILAUSU
    from usuarios;     
END;
```

error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Porque no me retorna el valor?